# Java Multithreading and Reading from Serial: How to Properly Suspend and Resume?

Tags: java, multithreading, swing, serial-port, arduino

I am trying to write a basic Java Swing application that works as such: an Arduino writes two CSV strings to the COM port every second, I read that data and parse it, and then display the data in a GUI. With some help from the official Arduino tutorials, I am at the point where I can read and parse the data coming in from the serial port, and display it. However, I would be able to pause and resume the GUI (while still reading from serial) using a key on the keyboard. I was able to pause the program, but cannot figure out how to resume it. I've been looking around online for a while now to no avail. If someone could point me in the right direction, I'd sincerely appreciate it. I'm rather new to threads and the Arduino, but have some basic Java experience. Here is the code below, which is broken up into three classes (one to read from serial, one for the GUI, and a main class to run everything. Thanks!

Here is the "Display" class:

```
//Imports
import java.awt.*;
import javax.swing.*;
import java.util.Random;
import java.lang.Thread;
import java.awt.event.*;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.awt.Toolkit.*;

//Class Definition
public class Display extends JPanel implements Runnable {
//Variables
private volatile Thread t;
private volatile boolean threadSuspended;

//Data Strings
private String data;
private String carData;
private String gpsData;

//Car Data
private int event;
private int engineRPM;
private int cvtRPM;
private double kph;
private int brake;
private double accel_x;
private double accel_y;
private double accel_z;
private double gyro_x;
private double gyro_y;
private double gyro_z;

//GPS Data
private String sentence;
private int time;
private String status;
private double latitude;
private String latitudeDir;
private double longitude;
private String longitudeDir;
private double knots;
private double angle;
private int date;
private double magVar;
private char magVarDir;
private String checksum;

//Constructor
public Display() {
    super.setSize(800,800);
    setLayout(new BorderLayout());
    addKeyListener(new KeyHandler());
    setFocusable(true);

    start();
}

public void start() {
    t = new Thread(this);
    t.start();
    threadSuspended = false;
}

public synchronized void stop() {
    t = null;
    notify();
    threadSuspended = true;
}

@Override
public void run() {
    Thread thisThread = Thread.currentThread();
    while(t == thisThread) {
        try {
            Thread.sleep(1000);
            synchronized(this) {
                while (threadSuspended && t == thisThread) {
                    wait();
                }
            }
        } catch (InterruptedException ie) {
            ie.printStackTrace();
        }
        repaint();
        save();
    }
}

@Override
public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
    super.paintComponent(g);
    kph = SerialReader.getKPH();
    System.out.println(kph);
    g.drawString("Speed of Car: " + kph, 35, 35);
}

//Writes values to a file and updates average values
public void save() {
    //Nothing here yet
}

private class KeyHandler extends KeyAdapter {
    @Override
    public synchronized void keyPressed(KeyEvent ke) {
        ke.consume();
        int key = ke.getKeyCode();
        if (key == KeyEvent.VK_SPACE) {
            threadSuspended = !threadSuspended;
            if (!threadSuspended) {
                notify();
            }
        }
    }
}
}
```

Here is the "SerialReader" class:

```
//Imports
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.io.OutputStream;
import gnu.io.CommPortIdentifier; 
import gnu.io.SerialPort;
import gnu.io.SerialPortEvent; 
import gnu.io.SerialPortEventListener; 
import java.util.Enumeration;

//Class definition
public class SerialReader implements SerialPortEventListener {

//Data Strings
private static String data;
private static String carData;
private static String gpsData;

//Car Data
private static int event;
private static int engineRPM;
private static int cvtRPM;
private static double kph;
private static int brake;
private static double accel_x;
private static double accel_y;
private static double accel_z;
private static double gyro_x;
private static double gyro_y;
private static double gyro_z;

//GPS Data
private static String sentence;
private static int time;
private static String status;
private static double latitude;
private static String latitudeDir;
private static double longitude;
private static String longitudeDir;
private static double knots;
private static double angle;
private static int date;
private static double magVar;
private static char magVarDir;
private static String checksum;

//Variables
SerialPort serialPort;
private static final String[] PORT_NAMES = {"/dev/tty.usbserial-A9007UX1", "/dev/ttyUSB0", "COM3"};
private BufferedReader input;
private OutputStream output;
private static final int TIME_OUT = 2000;
private static final int DATA_RATE = 9600;

//Constructor
public SerialReader() {}

//Opens port
public void initialize() {
    CommPortIdentifier portId = null;
    Enumeration portEnum = CommPortIdentifier.getPortIdentifiers();

    while (portEnum.hasMoreElements()) {
        CommPortIdentifier currPortId = (CommPortIdentifier) portEnum.nextElement();
        for (String portName : PORT_NAMES) {
            if (currPortId.getName().equals(portName)) {
                portId = currPortId;
                break;
            }
        }
    }
    if (portId == null) {
        System.out.println("Could not find COM port.");
        return;
    }

    try {
        // open serial port, and use class name for the appName.
        serialPort = (SerialPort) portId.open(this.getClass().getName(),
                TIME_OUT);

        // set port parameters
        serialPort.setSerialPortParams(DATA_RATE,
                SerialPort.DATABITS_8,
                SerialPort.STOPBITS_1,
                SerialPort.PARITY_NONE);

        // open the streams
        input = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(serialPort.getInputStream()));
        output = serialPort.getOutputStream();

        // add event listeners
        serialPort.addEventListener(this);
        serialPort.notifyOnDataAvailable(true);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        //Do nothing
    }
}

//Called when port is no longer in use
public synchronized void close() {
    if (serialPort != null) {
        serialPort.removeEventListener();
        serialPort.close();
        System.out.println("Port Closed");
    }
}

//Reads data from serial port
public synchronized void serialEvent(SerialPortEvent spe) {
    if (spe.getEventType() == SerialPortEvent.DATA_AVAILABLE) {
        try {
            data = input.readLine();
            //System.out.println(data);
            if (data.charAt(0) == '$') {
                gpsData = data;
                parseGPSData(data);
            } else {
                carData = data;
                parseCarData(data);
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            //Do nothing
        }
    }
}

//Parse car data
public void parseCarData(String data) {
    String[] info = data.split(",");

    event = Integer.parseInt(info[0]);
    engineRPM = Integer.parseInt(info[1]);
    cvtRPM = Integer.parseInt(info[2]);
    kph = Double.parseDouble(info[3]);
    brake = Integer.parseInt(info[4]);
    accel_x = Double.parseDouble(info[5]);
    accel_y = Double.parseDouble(info[6]);
    accel_z = Double.parseDouble(info[7]);
    gyro_x = Double.parseDouble(info[8]);
    gyro_y = Double.parseDouble(info[9]);
    gyro_z = Double.parseDouble(info[10]);
}

//Parse GPS data
public void parseGPSData(String data) {
    String[] info = data.split(",");

    sentence = info[0];
    int time = Integer.parseInt(info[1]);
    status = info[2];
    latitude = Double.parseDouble(info[3]);
    latitudeDir = info[4];
    longitude = Double.parseDouble(info[5]);
    longitudeDir = info[6];
    knots = Double.parseDouble(info[7]);
    angle = Double.parseDouble(info[8]);
    date = Integer.parseInt(info[9]);
    magVar = Double.parseDouble(info[10]);
    magVarDir = info[11].charAt(0);
    checksum = info[11].substring(1);
}

//Accessor Methods
public static String getCarData() {
    return carData;
}

public static String getGPSData() {
    return gpsData;
}

public static int getEvent() {
    return event;
}

public static int getEngineRPM() {
    return engineRPM;
}

public static int getCvtRPM() {
    return cvtRPM;
}

public static double getKPH() {
    return kph;
}

public static int getBrake() {
    return brake;
}

public static double getAccel_X() {
    return accel_x;
}

public static double getAccel_Y() {
    return accel_y;
}

public static double getAccel_Z() {
    return accel_z;
}

public static double getGyro_X() {
    return gyro_x;
}

public static double getGyro_Y() {
    return gyro_y;
}

public static double getGyro_Z() {
    return gyro_z;
}

public static String getSentence() {
    return sentence;
}

public static int getTime() {
    return time;
}

public static String getStatus() {
    return status;
}

public static double getLatitude() {
    return latitude;
}

public static String getLatitudeDir() {
    return latitudeDir;
}

public static double getLongitude() {
    return longitude;
}

public static String getLongitudeDir() {
    return longitudeDir;
}

public static double getKnots() {
    return knots;
}

public static double getAngle() {
    return angle;
}

public static int getDate() {
    return date;
}

public static double getMagVar() {
    return magVar;
}

public static char getMagVarDir() {
    return magVarDir;
}

public static String getChecksum() {
    return checksum;
}
}
```

And lastly, the "Main" class:

```
//Imports
import java.awt.*;
import javax.swing.*;

//Class Definition
public class Main {
//Variables
private static JFrame frame;
private static Display display;
private static Container pane;
private static Dimension dim;
private static SerialReader sr;
private static Thread t;

//Run the program
public static void main(String[] args) {
    sr = new SerialReader();
    sr.initialize();
    t = new Thread() {
        public void run() {
            try {
                Thread.sleep(1000000);
            } catch (InterruptedException ie) {
                //Do nothing
            }
        }
    };
    t.start();
    System.out.println("Started");

    //Set look and feel to that of OS
    try {
        UIManager.setLookAndFeel(UIManager.getSystemLookAndFeelClassName());
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    frame = new JFrame("Baja GUI, Version 0.1");
    frame.setSize(800,800);
    frame.setResizable(false);
    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

    display = new Display();

    pane = frame.getContentPane();
    pane.add(display);

    //Place frame in the middle of the screen
    dim = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getScreenSize();
    frame.setLocation(dim.width/2-frame.getSize().width/2, dim.height/2-frame.getSize().height/2);

    frame.setVisible(true);
}
}
```

Comment: note that [`Thread.sleep()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Thread.html#sleep(long)) is static so `thisThread.sleep(1000);t.sleep(1000);` causes the current thread to sleep for two seconds

Comment: Oops that was silly, forgot to delete and comment some things out when I was messing around. Thanks for pointing it out anyway!

Comment: Use [`SwingWorker`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/).